# Integrating JBoss ESB Tools and Maven Integration for Eclipse (M2E)

Tags: maven-2, eclipse-indigo, jboss-esb

How do I go about creating a Maven project in Eclipse that is also recognizable to JBoss ESB Tools.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This should help - and then once you've created the project, you can either import or create a new project and use your project's root directory as the base directory for your Eclipse project.

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossESBTrailblazerBuildingWithMaven2